# How to reference app in .kv? Any reference ends with AttributeError

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to use attribute from app but any reference ends up with:
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'**
Here is part of my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

class FightScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


# design constructor
kv = Builder.load_file('AppDesign.kv')

class Design(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Design, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_hero = MainHero() # Tried main_hero = MainHero() too
        self.val = self.main_hero.nick  # string

    # Construct app
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Design().run()
```

```
# Using kv 2.0
ScreenManagement:
    id: screen_manager
    FightScreen:
        name: 'FightScreen'
        manager: screen_manager
        id: fight_screen

<FightScreen>

FloatLayout:
     BasicBackground
     Label:
          text: app.val
          pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .35}
```

Any attempt for reference app in .kv will lead to error.
I tried using

> `StringProperty`;
> `apply_property(**kwargs)`;
> reference through `ScreenManagement`/ `FightScreen`
>
> > *Problems to access app attributes too*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `app` attribute is `None` until the `App` is created. Just move the loading of the `kv` into the `build()` method of the `App`, so that it is not executed until the `App` is created:

```
class Design(App):
    val = StringProperty('default')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Design, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_hero = MainHero() # Tried main_hero = MainHero() too

    # Construct app
    def build(self):
        # design constructor
        kv = Builder.load_file('AppDesign.kv')
        return kv
```

Comment: It's easier than I though, I was trying to do this for more than 2 days, and It is this simple

Comment: But when my `val` change, label won't change, I found clock, but is here some func like: on_value_change_refresh(widget) ?

Comment: If you make `val` a [StringProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#module-kivy.properties) of your `App`, the updates will be handled automatically by kivy.

Comment: I added to `__init__ of class Design(App)` `self.val=StringProperty(self.main_hero.nick)` but when I access it in kv like this `app.val` It will return something like *<StringProperty name=>*

Comment: Define the `val` property outside of any method, but within the `Design` class definition. See my updated answer.

Comment: I tried this but how will I put in that variable attribute:`self.main_hero.nick`

Comment: If I do something like *inside init* `self.val = self.main_hero.nick` or `global \ val = self.main_hero.nick` or  `val = StringProperty(self.main_hero.nick)` label won't update on value change
I have separate question for his: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391902/how-to-update-label-text-in-kv-using-properties-in-py