# How to update label text in .kv using properties in .py?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to update values in my class `MainHero` using button in *.kv* and based on attribute `nick` in my class I need to update label in *.kv*.
I need to handle this automatically, because many other attributes will be generated automatically so **labels** need to be updated.
Here is part of my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import *
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MainHero():
     def __init__(self):
          self.nick = "Player"

class FightScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FightScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.af_init = Clock.create_trigger(self._init)
        self.af_init()

    def _init(self, dt):
         self.app = App.get_running_app()
    
    def rename(self):
        self.app.main_hero.nick = "Renamed"


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass



class Design(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Design, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_hero = MainHero() # Tried main_hero = MainHero() too
        self.val = StringProperty(self.main_hero.nick)  # string

    # Construct app
    def build(self):
        # design constructor
        kv = Builder.load_file('AppDesign.kv')
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Design().run()
```

```
# Using kv 2.0
ScreenManagement:
    id: screen_manager
    FightScreen:
        name: 'FightScreen'
        manager: screen_manager
        id: fight_screen

<FightScreen>

FloatLayout:
     Label:
          text: app.val
          size_hint: .2, .2
          pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .35}
     Button:
          size_hint: .2, .2
          pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
          on_press:
               root.rename()
```

It is probably possible through properties/EventDispetcher.
Reference app.val in many cases I tried is something like *<StringProperty name=>*.
I tried using (maybe wrong)

> `class Aaa(EventDispetcher)`;
> `apply_property(**kwargs)`
> I want to do that with `ObjectProperty` too, it's different I think and I have no idea how to do it.

**Edit:**

```
     def rename(self):
          self.app.main_hero.nick = "Renamed"
          self.app.main_hero.num += 1
          self.app.val = self.app.main_hero  # not working need replace
          # probably something here (replacement)

class MainHero():
     def __init__(self):
          self.nick = "Player"
          self.num = 1
.
.
.
class Design(App):
     val = ObjectProperty()

     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Design, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_hero = MainHero() # Tried main_hero = MainHero() too
        self.val = self.main_hero  # object
```

```
.
.
.
Label:
     text: app.val.nick
     size_hint: .2, .2
     pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .35}
Label:
     text: str(app.val.num)
     size_hint: .2, .2
     pos_hint: {'center_x': .7, 'center_y': .7}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StringProperty` must be defined outside of a class method, like this:

```
class Design(App):
    val = StringProperty()  # defines the val property
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Design, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_hero = MainHero()  # Tried main_hero = MainHero() too
        self.val = self.main_hero.nick  # set value of the property
```

Then, in your `rename()` method, you can just change the value of `app.val`

```
def rename(self):
    self.app.main_hero.nick = "Renamed"
    self.app.val = self.app.main_hero.nick
```

If you want to use the values in the `MainHero` class directly in `kv`, they must be `Properties`. But to make those attributes into `Properties`, the `MainHero` class must be a `Widget` or at least an `EventDispatcher`, like this:

```
class MainHero(EventDispatcher):
    nick = StringProperty()
    num = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        self.nick = "Player"
        self.num = 1
```

Comment: Works for `NumericProperty` too, but you can't use `f` *string*, you need to convert it through `str()` *in .kv*

Comment: Would this work for `ObjectProperty` if I am accessing attributes directly in *.kv*? I tried but am not able figure it out, probably you know

Comment: Works for any `Property`, but you must be aware of what you are using it for. As @master points out, you can use a `NumericProperty` for the `text` of a `Label` as long as you convert it to a string. Similarly, if you use an `ObjectProperty`, you must extract an appropriately typed object from the referenced object.

Comment: I know what you mean, and I tried it but not working, look at my edit

Comment: The problem is that the automatic update done by kivy only works for `Properties`, but the `nick` and `num` attributes of `MainHero` are not `Properties`. Try changing your `MainHero` class as in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an ID for the label in the kv file and refer the action by which you want to change the text to a callback function, then change the text of the label in this way.

kv:

```
MDLabel:
        id: number
        text: "1"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

py:

```
class Screen2(Screen, n):
    def set_number(self):
        self.ids.number.text = f"{n}"
```

Comment: I know about this way, and I wrote I can't do it like this